# What lens should I buy?

Tags: lens, equipment-recommendation, canon, macro, wide-angle

Im going on a Caribbean Cruise this winter and I just recently purchased the Canon Rebel T4i 18MP DSLR Camera Package which come with...

1. Canon Rebel T4i 18MP DSLR Camera With 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6 IS II Lens Kit
2. Canon EF-S 55-250mm f/4-5.6 IS Lens
3. Canon T2i/T3i/T4i Accessory Kit

I wanted to know if you would recommend I buy a wide angle lens for scenic photo's? If not wide angle what in your opinion is better? Possibly macro?

Comment: If it were possible to answer this question, Canon would only make one lens. What needs and wants do _you_ have? If you figure that out, the lens requirements will come naturally.

Comment: Absolutely impossible to tell without knowing where you are going, what kind of subjects you shoot, etc and what you intend to do with your images.

Answer (score 5):

The standard 18-55mm kit lens that the camera came with is a very standard range. You can capture most things that you could capture with basically any general purpose camera would. The 55-250mm lens is quite a large zoom, allowing you to capture things farther away, and the range of this even further extends what you can do. If you were set on capturing birds on your cruise for example, 250mm might be too short - but this is just an example. If you are planning on capturing the interiors of the cruise ship rooms - 18mm might be not wide enough - but this is just an example. We can't tell you what to buy, because you don't tell us anything about what you plan to shoot or what you are limited by.

I will say that both of the lenses that you own do not have very wide apertures. You may struggle to capture a scene with great bokeh, and you may struggle to capture very low light scenes with action. f/3.5 is your widest aperture and that is only when zoomed out with the 18-55mm. If you don't quite understand this yet, I would recommend learning your camera and this limitation before you just go out and purchase something.

**What lens should I buy?** - No lenses. Go take pictures!

Answer (score 1):

What lens you should buy depends on what pictures you want to take and how your current lens won't take them. With your current lenses you're covered for quite a wide range of pictures. The only thing I can think of is if you were to get the 18-200 or 28-300 because of the wider zoom range, but that won't get you much better pictures, it's just more convenient to use one lens instead of two.

But back to the real answer: use what you have until it won't do what you want it to.

And by the way, 18mm is pretty wide. If you want to get wider than that you need to buy an expensive lens and/or a full frame body.